# Is there an easier way to find the inverse of a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

I know the normal process is to do row operations to transform the matrix to get the identity matrix and then apply the same row operations in the identity matrix to get the inverse. But this process seems so tedious and I'd rather not waste so much time and energy doing the row operations to get it.

Is there some sort of general formula or shortcut to obtain the inverse similar to how the inverse of a 2x2's inverse is found? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices

Comment: If the matrix has a nonzero determinant $|A|$ (as an invertible matrix must), the entries of the inverse can be expressed by the usual ratios of (signed) cofactors to $|A|$.  So you wind up computing nine $2\times 2$ determinants in addition to $|A|$.  Is that easier or not?

Comment: If you carry out the calculations one time with symbols instead of numbers, then you have a result that can be reused for any 3x3 matrix

Comment: Why do you need to find the inverse of a $3 \times 3$ matrix anyway?

Comment: I've always used the formula that is given by Jessica K in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to recall that, for $\operatorname{det}(A)\neq 0$,

$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{det}(A)} \operatorname{adj}(A)$$

and use the [Rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to calculate $\operatorname{det}(A)$. Whether that is easier or not is debatable, but the formula for a $2\times 2$ matrix is basically this.

Comment: If $a_{22} \neq 0$, then the calculation of $\det(A)$ may as well be done by [Dodgson's method of condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation) since the required $2\times 2$ determinants are already at hand.  If $a_{22} = 0$, then a workaround is possible, if slightly more awkward, assuming $A$ is indeed invertible.